Support two styles of parameter on same route?
In my C# ASP.Net Core application, I have this endpoint:
public string Example(int? id = null)

Is there a simple way to set up the routing so that all of these paths work?

/Controller/Example/2 - Sets id to 2
/Controller/Example?id=2 - Sets id to 2
/Controller/Example - Sets id to null

I'm dealing with a large historical codebase with sketchy documentation and upgrading the project from ASP.Net Framework to ASP.Net Core. With the ASP.Net Framework code, both styles of specifying the id in the URL were handled automagically.1 It's not clear that the client doesn't have other apps that use both forms when calling into this API (yes, of course I'm trying to find out), so ideally I'd like to continue to support both.
I've had a good read of the this page from the routing documentation, but I'm none the wiser. :-) This isn't one of my core areas.
I've tried multiple Route attributes, like this:
// (The controller's name differs from what we want on the endpoint [sigh] which is why it's given explicitly here)
[Route("Controller/[action]")]
[Route("Controller/[action]/{id?}")]
public string Example(int? id = null)

...but /Controller/Example?id=2 runs the method without setting id to 2. Each of those routes works for one of the styles when it's the only attribute on the method, but when they're both there, /Controller/Example?id=2 doesn't work (id is null).
I could write code to do this, or have two endpoints, but is there a simpler way?

1 "handled automagically" — I think it's this code in Global.asax.cs that enables that automagic behavior in the old code:
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(                               // <==
        name: "DefaultApi",                                   // <==
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",          // <==
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });      // <==
});


It can be done by putting 2 parameters in the Action Method with different binding sources and using whichever has a value (with precedence), see below.
It makes use of the fact that Route parameter names are not visible to the outside world.
[Route("Controller/[action]")]
[Route("Controller/[action]/{routeId?}")]
public IActionResult Example([FromRoute] int? routeId = null, [FromQuery] int? id = null)
{
    return View(id ?? routeId); // Or `routeId ?? id` if you prefer
}

Results:
/Controller/Example        --> null
/Controller/Example/3      --> 3
/Controller/Example/?id=5  --> 5
/Controller/Example/3?id=5 --> 5  // gave precedence to id= 

